# Can you receive events for Analog Output and Binary output in DNP3 protocol?

Tags: network-protocols

We are implementing a DNP3 master application. In Report By Exception poll we seem to receive only the data change info for input types. i.e. Analog Input, Binary Input. We don't receive any info for Analog Output or Binary Output. We have gone through the protocol specs, but haven't come across anything that confirms the same.

Answer (score 0):

Master sends out binary output, station sends back binary output status. If you do not send, you can't receive.